# @media handheld - no hover effects

Tags: css, hover

For a current project, I am trying to remove hover effects on devices with a touch screen. My plan is to use `@media handheld { /* non-hover styles here */ }`, paste here everything in my css file that has `:hover` on it, and just remove all the hover effects.

Example:

```
/* desktop */

a.my_element {
color : #ff0000;
}
a.my_element:hover {
color : #000000;
}

/* handheld devices */

@media handheld {
a.my_element:hover {
}
}
```

Is my logic correct? Will this work?

Comment: You need to explicitly state the hover effects you wish to remove in the query.

Comment: I don't get it (?) - I want to remove all hover effects, site-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="my_element"> example </a>
```

CSS

```
a.my_element {
color : #ff0000;
}
a.my_element:hover {
color : #000000;
}

/* handheld devices */

@media (max-width: 480px){
    a.my_element:hover {
        color: #ff0000;           
    }
}
```

This will pretty much use the media query at 460px to style the hover to be the exact same color as if it were not hovered (ultimately creating what you would like to do).

**[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39574/2/)**

Comment: But why can't I just add an EMPTY a.my_element:hover ? The effect should be the same...

Comment: But it's not, simply because you're not specifying what should happen at that width. If you don't put anything, then the media query doesn't do anything because you didn't specify it. However, if you add the color it is to become, then the media query can acknowledge this and execute the CSS. Basically adding an EMPTY space is keeping the same hover effects from before.

Comment: If this helps, check my answer as correct to help other people looking for the same answer!